# JavaScript RegEx - Matching One Expression First, then another

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to use a JavaScript regular expression to check a string for anything that matches a certain set of letters followed by either 5 or 6 numbers. For example, if the string is `'MyValue12345 blah blah MyValue123456 blah MyValue222221'`, it should return a match of `['MyValue12345', 'MyValue123456', 'MyValue222221']`. I'm a RegEx novice (clearly), and my expression gets close but not exactly what I'm looking for...

Here is my first try:

```
var str = 'MyValue12345 blah blah MyValue123456 blah MyValue222221';
var matchArr = str.match(/MyValue\d\d\d\d\d|MyValue\d\d\d\d\d\d/gi);
```

`matchArr` then equates to `['MyValue12345', 'MyValue123456', 'MyValue22222']`, but the last value of `MyValue22222` isn't what I'm looking for, I want it to say the full expression of `MyValue222221`. I know there's a better way to do this but I'm struggling to get it...any thoughts?

Comment: I'm getting `["MyValue12345", "MyValue12345", "MyValue22222"]`

Comment: Yeah I think I had some typos; I've since made some edits...but basically I want the last element to be `MyValue222221` rather than `MyValue22222`.

Comment: You could use `+` to make the selection greedy? `MyValue\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [quantifier range {n,m}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range) ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BliDUu/1)):

```js
var str = 'MyValue12345 blah blah MyValue123456 blah MyValue222221';
var matchArr = str.match(/MyValue\d{5,6}/gi);

console.log(matchArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex tries to apply the first pattern of your [`|` alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), and when that matches that's the result. Only when it doesn't match, it will try the second alternative. So you would swap the two to make it work:

```
/MyValue\d\d\d\d\d\d|MyValue\d\d\d\d\d/gi
```

However, that's quite repetitive - better use a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the difference:

```
/MyValue\d\d\d\d\d(?:\d|)/gi
//                ^^^^^^^ one digit or none
```

You can shorten that syntactically with a [`?` modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) that will match "one or nothing":

```
/MyValue\d\d\d\d\d\d?/gi
//                ^^^ one digit or none
```

Last but not least you'll want to have a look at [repetition syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
/MyValue\d{5}\d?/gi
//      ^^^^^ five digits
/MyValue\d{5,6}/gi
//      ^^^^^ five or six digits
```